# how can i show a matplotlib graph on html page?

Tags: python, php, matplotlib, xampp

i am using below code to get live **scraped** data from tiktok (trending hashtag and number of views)
then i make two list out of them and draw a graph
ater this i am running my python  script in xampp server.

here is my code

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt,mpld3


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.tiktok.com/"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
result = soup.find_all('span' , {'class' : "lazyload-wrapper"})
len(result)

trending = []
viewss = []
for item in result[0]:
    for j in item:
        type(item)
        #print(item[0])
        tak = item.find_all("a","jsx-2474431524")
        a = range(len(tak))
        #print(a[4])
        for i in range(len(tak)):
            url = "https://www.tiktok.com/"+tak[i].get("href")
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
            result = soup.find_all('div' , {'class' : "share-info"})
            views = result[0].h2.text
            if 'B' in views:
                lists = result[0].h1.text
                #view = result[0].h2.text
                print(lists)
                print(views)
                trending.append(lists)
                viewss.append(views)
                
                
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xval=[]
lent = len(trending)
for i in range(lent):
    xval.append(i)

x = trending
y = viewss

#print(trending[3], )

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('trends', size = 15)
plt.ylabel('Ranking', size = 15)
#plt.title('', size = 10)

plt.xticks(rotation=-30)
plt.xticks(size = 20)
plt.yticks(size = 20)
fig.savefig('my_plot.png')
plt.show()
#mpld3.show()
```

code is running fine when i make matplotlib comment